# Deriving the reduction formula for $\int\cos^n x\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, reduction-formula

When they add $(n-1)\int \cos^{n}xdx$ to both sides of the equation how does $-(n-1)\int \cos^{n}xdx$ become $n\int \cos^{n}xdx$? Shouldn't it become $(n-1)\int \cos^{n}xdx$ on the left and the one on the right becomes zero?

[image]

Comment: LHS has $1$, so $n-1+1=n$.

Comment: Oh yes. I see now.

Comment: Because $1+(n-1)=n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int \cos^n x ~dx=\cos^{n-1}x~\sin~x+(n-1)\int \cos^{n-2}x~dx-(n-1)\int \cos^n x~dx\qquad . ..  . .. (1)$$
If you add both side by $$(n-1)\int \cos^n x~dx$$then $(1)$ becomes 
$$\int \cos^n x ~dx+(n-1)\int \cos^n x~dx=\cos^{n-1}x~\sin~x+(n-1)\int \cos^{n-2}x~dx-(n-1)\int \cos^n x~dx+(n-1)\int \cos^n x~dx$$
$$\implies (1+n-1)\int \cos^n x ~dx=\cos^{n-1}x~\sin~x+(n-1)\int \cos^{n-2}x~dx+\{(n-1)-(n-1)\}\int \cos^n x~dx$$
$$\implies n\int \cos^n x ~dx=\cos^{n-1}x~\sin~x+(n-1)\int \cos^{n-2}x~dx$$

---

**Alternative thought:**

$$\int \cos^n x ~dx=\cos^{n-1}x~\sin~x+(n-1)\int \cos^{n-2}x~dx-(n-1)\int \cos^n x~dx$$
$$\implies \int \cos^n x ~dx +(n-1)\int \cos^n x~dx=\cos^{n-1}x~\sin~x+(n-1)\int \cos^{n-2}x~dx$$
$$\implies (1+n-1)\int \cos^n x ~dx=\cos^{n-1}x~\sin~x+(n-1)\int \cos^{n-2}x~dx$$
$$\implies n\int \cos^n x ~dx=\cos^{n-1}x~\sin~x+(n-1)\int \cos^{n-2}x~dx$$